# bind collectionview footer to data xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, footer, android-databinding, collectionview

i have a collectionview with data that i get from sql server database using a web api. the collcetionview populates successfully. now i wanted to add a footer to display the total of debit and credit columns. but i couldn't make it work. this is the code of my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="isc_alphaApp.account_details">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Beige" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20,20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Text="" x:Name="acc_curlabel"/>
                    <CollectionView x:Name="accountdetailslst" Footer="{Binding}">
                        <CollectionView.Header>
                            <Grid Padding="2" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="Date"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       FontSize="14"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="Jv#"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                                        FontSize="14"
                                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                                     FontSize="14"
                       Text="Ref"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                
                        />
                                <Label
                       Grid.Column="3"
                                     FontSize="14"
                       Text="Description"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />
                                <Label
                                     FontSize="14"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="4"
                       Text="Debit"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />
                                <Label
                                     FontSize="14"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="5"
                       Text="Credit"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />
                                <Label
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="6"
                                     FontSize="14"
                       Text="Balance"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />

                            </Grid>


                        </CollectionView.Header>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />

                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding jvdate}"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                                           FontSize="12"/>

                                    <Label 
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding jvnbr}"
                      FontSize="12"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="2"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding jvref}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                        />

                                    <Label
                      TextColor="Black"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Text="{Binding desc}"
                                        FontSize="12"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />

                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="4"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding jvdebit}"
                                        FontSize="12"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />

                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="5"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding jvcredit}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />

                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="6"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding balance}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        FontSize="12"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <CollectionView.FooterTemplate  >
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="2" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" x:Name="gridfooter" >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="3"
                       Text="{Binding total}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               x:Name="total"
                                       FontSize="14"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>

                                <Label Grid.Column="4"
                               x:Name="totaldebit"
                       Text="{Binding Totjvdebit}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                       FontSize="12"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="5"
                       Text="{Binding Totjvcredit}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       FontSize="14"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="6"
                       Text="{Binding Totbalance}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       FontSize="14"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>

                            </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                    
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#ffc40c">
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckcol">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgAdd" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            <Label Text="del" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}" x:Name="col_add_remove"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckfilter">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgfilter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            <Label Text="Filter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckshare">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgshare" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            <Label Text="Share" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView x:Name="popupLoadingView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Black" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" ></ActivityIndicator>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

this is the code of my xaml.cs

```
 public partial class account_details : ContentPage
    {
       
        List<accountdetails> listacc_collection = new List<accountdetails>();
        public string total = "";
        public account_details(string acc, string cur, string accname)
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            imgAdd.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("isc_alphaApp.remove_ic.png");
            imgfilter.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("isc_alphaApp.filter_ic.png");
            imgshare.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("isc_alphaApp.share_icon.png");
            loadData(acc,cur,accname);
}

  async private void loadData(string account, string curr,string acc_name )
        {
            acc_curlabel.Text = account + " - " + curr + " - " + acc_name;
            popupLoadingView.IsVisible = true;
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "http://192.168.43.99/siteisc/api/values";
            string uri = url + "/getaccountdetails";
            
            try
            {

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var listacc_details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<allaccountdetails>>(content);
                    var list_filtered = listacc_details.FindAll(x => x.JvAccount == account && x.CurrencyCode == curr);
                    decimal blnce_row = 0;
                    List<String> l = new List<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list_filtered.Count; i++)
                    {
                        blnce_row = decimal.Parse(list_filtered[i].JvDebit.ToString()) - decimal.Parse(list_filtered[i].Jvcredit.ToString()) + blnce_row;
                        decimal rnd_blnce = Math.Round(blnce_row, 2);
                        l.Add(rnd_blnce.ToString());
                    }
                    l.ToArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < list_filtered.Count; i++)
                    {
                        listacc_collection.Add(new accountdetails { desc = list_filtered[i].JvDescription, jvnbr = list_filtered[i].jvnbr.ToString(), jvcredit = list_filtered[i].Jvcredit.ToString(), jvdate = DateTime.Parse(list_filtered[i].JvDate).ToString(("dd-M-yyyy")), jvdebit = list_filtered[i].JvDebit.ToString(), jvref = list_filtered[i].jvref1, balance = l[i] });
                    }
                    var list_acc_footer = new List<footeraccount>();
                    list_acc_footer.Add(new footeraccount { total = "Total in" + " " + curr, Totjvdebit = getTotal_dbt(listacc_collection), Totjvcredit = getTotal_crdt(listacc_collection),Totbalance= getTotal_dbt(listacc_collection) - getTotal_crdt(listacc_collection) });
                    accountdetailslst.ItemsSource = listacc_collection;
                    total = "Total in" + " " + curr;
                    popupLoadingView.IsVisible = false;
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", "Response Failed!", "Cancel");
                }

            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exp)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Please Check Your Internet Connection!", "Cancel");
            }
        }
}
}
```

i tried to do something similar to the code in this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-using-listview-headertemplate-and-footertemplate-to-display-data/ but it didn't work. this is what i did:
footer.cs

```
 public class footer
    {
        public List<accountdetails> GetAll { get; private set; }

        public footer()
        {
            GetAll=new List<accountdetails> { new accountdetails { jvdate = "sksj", jvnbr = "idjd", desc = "kjsjs", balance = "ksjh", jvcredit = "4", jvdebit = "3", jvref = "jy" } };


        }
    }
```

AccountViewModel.cs:

```
 public class AccountViewModel
    {
        public string total = "";
        public List<accountdetails> items { get; private set; }
        public AccountViewModel()
        {
            var service = new footer();
            items = service.GetAll;
            total = service.GetAll.Count.ToString();
           

        }
    }
}
```

and in the xaml.cs i just wrote this:

```
  public account_details(string acc, string cur, string accname)
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new AccountViewModel();
}
```

but it didn't work. nothing appeared in my footer. what should i do?
thanks in advance

Comment: When that page appears, is there a warning in VS Output saying that it couldn't find some property to bind to? any mention of `Totjvdebit` in VS Output?

Comment: you can only bind to public properties - `total` is public, but it is not a C# property

Comment: And `Totjvdebit` likewise must be a public property in AccountViewModel. Something like `public string Totjvdebit { get; set; }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding: Property not found. MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528844/binding-property-not-found-mvvm)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks a lot for replying sir. no i don't get any warning. just nothing appears in the footer

Comment: @Jason thanks for replying sir, i'll try to add get and set and see what happens

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve aah okay i'll fix this. one more thing sir, i changed the total into a c# property as you and @Jason suggested. it worked. but now i'm wondering what to do. in my xaml.cs, i access my views like the images ``` imgAdd.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("isc_alphaApp.remove_ic.png");``` and other things. if i use the ```AccountViewModel```, how will i perform those things?

Comment: Please create a new question, showing the code you do now for images, and the AccountViewModel that works now. Try to write the code you would need, where it would belong (in AccountViewModel I guess?) When you get to the point in code where you would need to access the image, put a comment indicating what you are trying to do - but don't know how to. This will make it clearer to anyone else exactly what help is needed.

Comment: why don't you just hardcode the image sources in the XAML?  Or you can continue to define them in the code behind, or you can bind them to VM properties.  Any of those approaches are valid.  But if the images don't change then just defining them in the XAML would be the easiest

Comment: thanks everyone for your help. i kept the code as it was in the beginning and just changed the variables ```total```, ```Totjvdebit``` and the others into c# properties, as you suggested, in my xaml.cs code like this:```public string total { get; private set; }
        public decimal Totjvdebit { get; private set; }
        public decimal Totjvcredit { get; private set; }
        public decimal Totbalance { get; private set; }``` and added this line ```InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;``` and everything worked as i wished. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Poster (rana hd) says in a comment on the question, that making those fields properties worked.

E.g. what was this in the view model:

```
public string total = "";
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
public string total { get; set; } = "";
```